# Given the below definition of runDB, will the second insert rollback upon failure of the first?

Tags: yesod, persistent

I'm using Yesod as the framework, postgresql as the DB, and have the following definition of `runDB`. Looking at the docs on the Yesod site, I have a hunch that using `runDB` in the following manner will cause a rollback of the first `insert` upon the failure of the second. Am I right. If not, how do I invoke a rollback?

```
instance YesodPersist App where
    <snip>
    runDB action = do
        master <- getYesod
        runSqlPool action $ appConnPool master


addKitteh :: Kitteh -> Handler (Either StoreError StoreResult)
addKitteh (Kitteh desc color size photo) = do
    data_key <- runDB $ do
                         data_key <- insert (KittehDesc desc color size)
                         insert (KittehPic data_key photo)
...
```

edit - Also, what happens if the first `insert` fails?

edit - I thought the model might be significant

```
KittehDesc json
   blurb Text
   color Color
   size KittehSize
   deriving Show

KittehPic
  kittehId KittehDescId Eq
  kittehPic Base64
  UniqueKittehId kittehId
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, everything in `runDB` is wrapped in a transaction. If the first insert fails an exception will be thrown, and the code won't reach the second insert.

I think this is documented somewhere, but I just traced the code to come to this conclusion: `runDB` is implemented with [`defaultRunDB`](https://github.com/yesodweb/yesod/blob/d8414c3c2090d5918fdc6dce7d82f2f921e8631a/yesod-persistent/Yesod/Persist/Core.hs#L53), which calls into [`runPool`](https://github.com/yesodweb/persistent/blob/0fe7d27c7a029459efa22ac18a99b1354323c74b/persistent-postgresql/Database/Persist/Postgresql.hs#L956), which calls `runSqlPool`, which calls into `runSqlConn`, whic you can see is handling rollbacks when an exception occurs:

```
runSqlConn :: MonadBaseControl IO m => SqlPersistT m a -> SqlBackend -> m a
runSqlConn r conn = control $ \runInIO -> mask $ \restore -> do
    let getter = getStmtConn conn
    restore $ connBegin conn getter
    x <- onException
            (restore $ runInIO $ runReaderT r conn)
            (restore $ connRollback conn getter)
    restore $ connCommit conn getter
    return x
```